# Unable to uninstall a program [Ubuntu 20.04.1]

Tags: 20.04, synaptic

Rambox was causing a few issues for me and I wanted to remove it and reinstall it. When I tried to do it using the Store, I got this "error":
[Unable to remove "Rambox CE": Cannot perform the following tasks:.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1MI.png) I then tried to find it using the terminal to remove it from there, but it seemed like the package was not listed at all. I installed Synaptic to see if I can find it through that, but nope. Can't seem to find Rambox at all. The application still runs and is installed on my system. I'm really at my wits end here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The Software store can install multiple package types (you'd have to explore further down the page to see if it was *snap* or *deb*..).  Package tools like `synaptic` only list *deb* packages, and you didn't mention what command line tools you used to view (eg. did that include `snap list`? or did you only look with apt|dpkg tools?)

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for the info. I used `dpkg list--` in the terminal. The store tells me that the source of the application is snapcraft.io. Does that mean this is a snap package?

Comment: Yep, and try the `snap list` command I listed in prior comment, if it's there, you can remove with `snap remove` (or remove in snap store etc)